# Creative solution to two different JMS queue listeners (Tibco)

Tags: java, queue, jms, listener, tibco

We've got a situation where two different application instances intermittently listen at the same queue.

The logical solution is just to point one of them somewhere else or switch one off.

I wondered if there was a way to configure the Tibco JMS configuration to force one off, or only send message events to one client? I was looking for an 'out of the box' way of thinking about this issue.

Comment: JMS Queues only send a message to one listener.  That is what makes then different from Topics.  What is the problem you are actually seeing?

Comment: We're sending messages but only intermittently getting responses. It looks like the other queue listener is getting in first sometimes.

Comment: The message will only go to one destination, so you can't monitor a queue this way.  There are Queue Browsers but these are typically specific to your JMS server.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey - just answer 'no' - and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I believe the answer is; yes, that's the way it works now, which means you can't use it for monitoring which you don't mention in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the "exclusive" feature of EMS is what your are looking for...

By setting this property on the queue, only one listener can be listening at a time.

Here is a pertinent link : https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service_central_administration/1.0.1_may_2009/html/tib_ems_users_guide/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=EMS.5.028.htm&single=true

Answer (score 0):

The  msgs are always  equally distributed between the listeners.if you need you can use a message selector. If a QueueReceiver specifies a message selector, the messages that are not selected remain on the queue. By definition, a message selector allows a QueueReceiver to skip messages. This means that when the skipped messages are eventually read, the total ordering of the reads does not retain the partial order defined by each message producer. Only QueueReceivers without a message selector will read messages in message producer order.